# reference to value of an multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, recursion, reference

Im looking for a bit tricky thing :)

I have a multidimensional array like:

```
$array = array(
  "collection" => "departments",
  "action" => "find",
  "args" => array ("_id" => array("$in" => "{{variablename}}"))
);
```

I want to have the reference of value {{variablename}} in order to change it later.
It must be a recursive function because i can't predict where {{variablename}} is on the array.

Without recursivity no probs, but with I didn't find how I can do that.

PS: Other solutions to transform array to string or json and use replace does not interest me. I really need reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very pretty (also not recursive, which is a good thing), but should work:

```
// Input data
$array = array(
  "collection" => "departments",
  "action" => "find",
  "args" => array ("_id" => array('$in' => "{{variablename}}"))
);

// Create a stack
$stack = array(&$array);

// Loop until the stack is empty
while (sizeof($stack) > 0) {
    // Get the first variable in the stack (by reference)
    foreach ($stack as &$current) break;
    // Remove the first variable from the stack (by reference, same as array_shift but array_shift breaks the references) 
    $stack = array_slice($stack, 1);
    // If the shifted variable is an array
    if (is_array($current)) {
        // Add all the array's values to the stack (by reference)
        foreach ($current as &$value) {
            $stack[] =& $value;
        }
    } 
    // If the shifted variable is the one we want
    elseif ($current == '{{variablename}}') {
        // Stop the loop, leaving $current as the reference to the variable we want
        break;
    }
}
$current = 'test';
var_dump($current);
var_dump($array);
```

Example: http://ideone.com/hEzZk

Comment: Works fine thx. But I don't really anderstand how your code works :) but I will examine in details

Comment: @Kakawait it creates a stack data structure and add your array to it. Then it iterates until the stack is empty. Each iteration it shifts the top of the stack off (by reference), then if the shifted variable is an array it pushes each value onto the stack. Or else if the variable is the one you want, it breaks the loop leaving the current variable as the reference. Ill update to add comments.

Comment: Yeah thx, i anderstand 5 min after but i appreciate your comments. Finaly it's a good idea